# IndexError: list index out of range - sometimes it runs and some times it is not

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a situation that i am not sure how to solve.
sometimes when i run the program it's running perfectly and sometimes it says

```
list index out of range
```

the code:

```
hashtag_list = ['urban', 'hipster', 'retro']
for hashtag in hashtag_list:
    tag = randint(1,3)
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + hashtag_list[tag] + '/')
    sleep(5)
```

any suggestions? - it's not the whole code tho but i figured it's all i need. - please let me know if any other information is needed

Comment: list indices start from 0 in Python

Comment: indexes start with 0, try with `randint(0,2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python list are zeroed indexed. That means the first index of a list starts from `0`. So the indexes for `hastag_list` are `0, 1, 2`. However, `randint(1,3)` is inclusive, so `tag` will sometimes randomly be assigned `3`.

It should start to become clear what the problem is. Since the maximum index of `hashtag_list` is `2`, and `tag` is sometimes `3`, then sometimes you will be indexing `hashtag_list` out of range.

The simple solution would be to use `randint(0, 2)` rather than `randint(1, 3)`. However, a cleaner solution would be to use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to choose a random option from `hashtag_list`:

```
from random import choice

# ...

hashtag_list = ['urban', 'hipster', 'retro']
for hashtag in hashtag_list:
    tag = choice()    
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/' + hashtag_list[tag] + '/')
    sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

`randint(a, b)` produces a random integer in the range `[a, b]` inclusive, those sometimes when it doesn't work it's producing `3`, and `3` is beyond the list. Change it to `randint(0, 2)`, because in Python (and many other languages), a list with `n` elements' indices start from `0` and end at `n - 1`. Thus:

```
# elements:  ['urban', 'hipster', 'retro']
# indices:       0         1         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 
tag = randint(1,3) 
to 
tag = randint(0,2)